# Is it faster to use WSL commands instead of cmd commands for file manipulation?

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, bash, powershell

On Windows 10, it is possible to manipulate files through the command line via three separate built-in ways:

1. Powershell,
2. the command prompt, and through
3. bash commands via the WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux).

I've recently encountered a situation where I need to manipulate a couple hundred gigabytes of files (all of them are fairly small files, but there are a lot of them).

It seems to take Windows Explorer ages to discover all the files before it runs a copy or delete operation on them, and if that process ever gets interrupted I have to start all over again.

This got me using the command prompt to perform some of the operations I needed to perform. Both command prompt and WSL commands seem to work faster since they don't do a discovery operation before hand, but I'm not sure which of these ways is faster, or if there are other considerations I need to take into account when deciding which one to use (bugs/ stability, for instance).

Comment: IMO it's a matter o personal preferences and knowledge of the different shells. It also depends on the type of tasks to perform.

Comment: You forgot COMMAND.COM in your list (unless you use 64 bit Windows).

Comment: It also depends on what you are actually doing. For instance searching the entire drive for every .ps1 file is much faster in cmd.exe than Powershell.

Comment: Yes, I do use 64 bit Windows, but I realize my list may not be exhaustive. I tend to avoid powershell just because it is clunky and complains a lot, although it does have more powerful options. I was primarily interested in knowing if I could depend on WSL for speed and reliability more than cmd, but since WSL isn't really "native", I thought there might be some overhead there.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion is more effective to use an native GNU/Linux distro unstead of the subsystem. Command Prompt isn't bad but for now it is little bit outdated. I know the tool has many limitations and for some task you need to be really creative. I dunno maybe I work wrong with it... So PowerShell. This include many builtin interesting things and maybe not the same like Bash or Python but anyway good on a Windows way.